# What is called first: destructor of static object or atexit handler?

Tags: c++, destructor, atexit

Is the order guaranteed in this case or is it UB?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct TraceHelper
{
    TraceHelper()
    {
        cout << "TraceHelper::constructor()" << endl;
    }

    ~TraceHelper()
    {
        cout << "TraceHelper::destructor()" << endl;
    }
};

void trace_fn()
{
    static TraceHelper th;
    cout << "trace_fn()" << endl;
}

void my_atexit()
{
    cout << "my_atexit()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Entered main()" << endl;
    assert(0 == atexit(my_atexit));
    trace_fn();
    trace_fn();
    cout << "Exiting main()" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Entered main()
TraceHelper::constructor()
trace_fn()
trace_fn()
Exiting main()
TraceHelper::destructor()
my_atexit()
```

Comment: Perhaps [this `std::atexit` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) together with [this `std::exit` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) might clear it up? Only the order between registered exit-handlers is guaranteed.

Comment: It's an implementation detail.  My implementations on 6 platforms all register the static object's destructor using the `atexit` mechanism.  The CRT start routine (which itself calls `main`) then processes the registered `atexit` callbacks.  Both *order of construction* of global `static` objects, and *order of destruction* at program `exit` can be problematic (bugs!) if there are construction or destruction dependencies between global objects.  In casual conversation, I call them *order of construction catastrophe* and *order of destruction disaster*.

Comment: @Eljay The static object here is not **global** and the timing of its construction/initialisation is well-defined as the first time execution passes through the declaration.

Comment: @Elijay: The phrase you'll find in widespread use is "static initialization order fiasco" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof

Answer (score 2):

What we are looking here is the interaction between the main function and [std::exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit):

> Returning from the main function, [...] performs the normal function
> termination (calls the destructors of the variables with automatic
> storage durations) and then executes std::exit, passing the argument
> of the return statement (or ​0​ if implicit return was used) as
> exit_code.

As far as destruction of static objects are concerned, what is relevant to the question are the following lines:

> If the completion of the initialization of a static object A was
> sequenced-before the call to std::atexit for some function F, the call
> to F during termination is sequenced-before the start of the
> destruction of A.
>
> If the call to std::atexit for some function F was
> sequenced-before the completion of initialization of a static object
> A, the start of the destruction of A is sequenced-before the call to F
> during termination.

In the code in the question, the function `my_atexit()` is registered using `std::atexit()` before the creation of the static object `th` in the function `trace_fn()`. Thus, the call of the destructor of `TraceHelper` is happening before calling `my_atexit()`. The behavior is as expected.

Comment: I would prefer to see the word "guaranteed" rather than "expected" in the last sentence. Is it guaranteed?

Comment: @ivan_onys    "Is as expected" is probably more correct.   The standard describes what is required of a conforming implementation.   The standard cannot guarantee that any particular implementation will conform with every requirement of the standard.   In the real world, vendors decide to have non-conformance against one or more requirements, vendors choose to offer extensions (which may result in some non-conformance) and, of course, there are bugs (unintended flaws) in software.

Answer (score 1):

In your *specific* case (i.e., that of a **local** static object), [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) has this to say (in the "since C++11" part):

> 1. The destructors of objects with thread local storage duration that
>    are associated with the current thread, the destructors of objects
>    with static storage duration, and the functions registered with
>    `std::atexit` are executed concurrently, while maintaining the
>    following guarantees:
>     …
>     c) If the completion of the
>    initialization of a static object A was sequenced-before the call to
>    `std::atexit` for some function F, the call to F during termination is
>    sequenced-before the start of the destruction of A
>     d) If the call
>    to `std::atexit` for some function F was sequenced-before the
>    completion of initialization of a static object A, the start of the
>    destruction of A is sequenced-before the call to F during termination.

Thus, since `th` is initialized – *by definition* – the first time execution passes through it's declaration, then your call to `atexit` will be fully sequenced before the first call to `trace_fn()` and the consquent construction of `tf`. Thus, paragraph "d" in the above citation holds and the destruction/termination sequence you see is well-defined.

Here is the 'equivalent' section from [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 6.8.3.4 Termination      [basic.start.term]
>
> …
> <sup>5</sup>    If the
> completion of the initialization of an object with static storage
> duration strongly happens before a call to `std::atexit`, the call to
> the function passed to `std::atexit` is sequenced before the call to
> the destructor for the object. If a call to `std::atexit` strongly
> happens before the completion of the initialization of an object with
> static storage duration, the call to the destructor for the object is
> sequenced before the call to the function passed to `std::atexit`.
> …

(Here is the [equivalent section](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.term#5) from the latest, on-line Draft C++ Standard.)

Note, also, that the destructors of such block scope `static` objects and calls to registered `atexit` handlers are called 'concurrently' (see the comments on possible misuse of this term), with the provided guarantees, so you can have calls to multiple destructors 'intermingled' with calls to multiple exit handlers.

Comment: That's not what "concurrently" means in computer engineering.  Interleaved or intermingled would be correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair point - I went with "intermingled".

Comment: It's the bold word in the same sentence that's wrong (and in the quote from cppreference, but you don't have control over their miswording).

Comment: C++ has quite [a specific meaning for "concurrent"](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21) and it does not apply here.  At all.

Comment: @Ben OK, I debolded it, gave it some quotes and added a note referring to your comments.